# Pass Jenkins lock from one job to another

Tags: jenkins, locking

I have a requirement to pass Jenkins lock on a resource from one job to another Jenkins job.
Consider I have a resource called device-1, and 2 Jenkins jobs, JobA and JobsB, now I initiate a lock on device-1 from JobA, then realize device-1 is faulty and needs fixing, the fixing is done by JobB, so I will call JobB from JobA, during this transition time the lock on device-1 is released back into the pool where it can be acquired by other jobs waiting in queue for this resource.
So want to know if I can pass lock between 2 Jenkins jobs without releasing.

Jenkins releases the lock as soon as the stage is completed, so passing lock even between stages (not stage) is a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the "Stealing"-permission with the lockable resource-plugin. Other jobs can "steal" a locked resource under certain conditions. There's good documentation on the [plugin-info site](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/).